# Mac .bash_profile not adding PYTHONPATH to sys.path

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to add one of my modules to sys.path by editing .bash_profile but failing. My objective is being able to import one of my other Python modules. After I edit .bash_profile and do a `echo .$PYTHONPATH` the new path appears as expected. *BUT* when I print sys.path the new path is *not* listed and I can't import the module. Neither restarting or the command '''source ~/.bash_profile``` corrects the issue. Conclusion: .bash_profile is not having the expected result of appending the new path to sys.path. I've read everything I can find online and none of the solutions work. Environment is Mac Mojave 10.14.5. Thanks.

Comment: What is the result of `os.environ["PYTHONPATH"]`?

Comment: Are you *exporting* `PYTHONPATH`? Python cannot read an ordinary shell variable.

Comment: PMende:
`
>>> os.environ["PYTHONPATH"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'
`
So is Anaconda messing me up? Sorry, couldn't figure out how to format the above as code.

Comment: Try "PATH" instead of "PYTHONPATH"